# Android Studio is not showing quick fix lightbulb

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Fresh Install of Android Studio, intellij is not showing me errors in the editor.

No lightbulb, no red underlined text. To know where I made errors (even the simplest error like a missing ';' ) I have to compile my Android project .

I'm on x64 all the way & Java JDK 1.7_40.

Thanks !

Comment: Have you configured the sources folder correctly, i.e. `Mark as source root` in context menu?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the answer !

Just on top of the right scrollbar there is a small eye icon, wich is called "Code Analysis", it should be green if the file opened in the code editor is without errors.

So what was the problem ? It seems that code analysis is battery hungry and it is desactivated by default when your laptop is on Power Saving Mode.

Uncheck Power Saving Mode, and Voilà !

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem even though my 'show intention bulb' was checked in settings. The problem went away when I restarted android studio.

Answer (score 2):

answer:
Right click anywhere on code editor and select "**show context action**" option.
Done.

Answer (score 0):

MacOS : Option + Enter

Windows : Alt + Enter

Preferences/Settings > search Intention Bulb > check show intention bulb under General > Appearance

Answer (score 0):

***right click*** on empty space in any file (where we write code) -> Analyze -> Configure current file analisys -> Configure inspections -> in there check "Android" and "Java"

***or just press ctrl + shift + alt + H*** -> Configure inspections -> in there check "Android" and "Java"

Answer (score 0):

click **Dart Analysis** icon
you will see 3 dots called **Analyzer setting**
click the checkbox Scope analysis to the current package
and you will see the **red bulb again**

Answer (score -1):

double click on any flutter widget ther you go solution is there