# Android studio Quick fix bulb not showing on "Design" view

Tags: android

I am a beginner for Android Studio 4.1, recently started following up a "Android Developer" tutorial channel on YouTube. I am following up his classes and on his  design view he showed how to extract resource for click button, by click on yellow quick fix bulb which is not popping up on my design view.
I searched all over internet could not match my query accurately.

Comment: Maybe this post helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384362/android-studio-is-not-showing-quick-fix-lightbulb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio is not showing quick fix lightbulb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384362/android-studio-is-not-showing-quick-fix-lightbulb)

Comment: I am really sorry but that dint fix